# Verb meaning "to approach [someone] in a threatening manner"

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be the appropriate one-word verb for describing the act of threateningly approaching someone? For example, a boxer, a fighter or a person of the likes approaching a physically inferior person. Which verb would capture this situation?

The context is:

> This shows how she will continue to defend her point of view, even if she is being [approached] by a large, burly man.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your context, ***coerce*** comes close. Other synonymous words that convey this intent are: pressurize, force, compel, bully, threaten & intimidate (all from ODO).

> This shows how she will continue to defend her point of view, even if
>   she is being ***coerced*** by a large, burly man.

ODO:

> **[coerce](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/coerce)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Persuade (an unwilling person) to do something by using force or 
>   threats.
>   ‘they were coerced into silence’
>
> ‘Then there are concerns that, as part of the company's strategy, it
>   coerces you into revealing your personal details.’
>
> ‘I was never coerced or forced into doing anything I didn't like.’

Answer (score 0):

Consider [confront](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confront) [OXD]

> Come face to face with (someone) with hostile or argumentative intent

You could say

> This shows how she will continue to defend her point of view, even if she is being *confronted* by a large, burly man.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps 'menace'?

> To threaten harm to.
>
> To make a show of intention to harm.

(From Merriam Webster)